# Use differential form to prove meromorphic function on compact Riemann surface has same zeros and poles

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am reading mine's modular form note, proposition 1.12 states that the sum of residues of a differential form on compact Riemann surface is $0$. Then he states that applies this to $df/f$, then we can prove meromorphic function on compact Riemann surface has same zeros and poles.

I can not follows this, can someone help? I apologize if this question is too elementary.

Comment: Which parts are you not following? The one for the differential form or the application to $df/f$?

Comment: I suggest you pick a meromorphic function on C, find the poles of f'/f and compute its residues there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I see, thanks, sorry about the elementary question.